# ValueError in 2D array python assignment

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, runtime-error

Can someone explain me this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(1,11)
>>> a.shape
(10,)
>>> a = a.reshape(1,10)
>>> a.shape
(1, 10)
>>> a[0]
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
>>> a[0].shape
(10,)
>>> a[0] = []
>>> a
ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 0 to array axis with dimension 10
>>> a
    array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10]])
```

**Why I get this error?**

Why I get the error in the line below and not immediately?
After the assignment it does not matter what I write:
i.e.

```
>>> a[0] = []
>>> b = 4
ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 0 to array axis with dimension 10
```

I am working with

```
>>> print sys.version
2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)]
>>> np.version.version
'1.8.0rc1'
```

Comment: Not clear what you want to do,  why does `a = np.array([[]])` not do what you want?

Comment: I can't reproduce what you're seeing. When I try it, I get the error on `a[0] = []`, as expected.

Comment: Seem here. Got the error on `a[0] = []`. What is the version of numpy you are using?

Comment: @skyline75489 the version is printed in the question.

Comment: I mean the version of numpy?

Comment: @user2357112 ... OK I get the error later, but I cannot understand why I can not do `a[0] = []` ?

Comment: What do you expect `a[0] = []` to do?

Comment: I expect to have `a` as `array([], shape=(1, 0))` the same of writing `np.array([[]])`

Comment: NumPy arrays have fixed shape. You can't perform operations that would change the shape of an array; you have to make a new array. This is critical to their efficiency.